# How to comapre two columns of a table in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In a table there are two columns:

```
 -----------     
 | A  |  B |
 -----------
 | 1  |  5 |
 | 2  |  1 |
 | 3  |  2 |
 | 4  |  1 |
 -----------
```

Want a table where if A=B then

```
  -------------------
  |Match  | notMatch|
  -------------------
  |  1    |    5    |
  |  2    |    3    |
  | Null  |    4    |
  -------------------
```

How can i do this?

I tried something which shows the Matched part

```
select distinct C.A as A from Table c  inner join Table d on c.A=d.B
```

Comment: Can you please provide your result data example.

Comment: question is not at all clear

Comment: To elaborate on @mmhasannn's comment, there is no discernible pattern in your result table. (Or tables? It's really hard to tell if those are separate or not.)

Comment: I think the idea is that a datum should appear in the Match column iff it appears anywhere in the A column and anywhere in the B column. Else, it should appear in the notMatch column.

Comment: If a=b then the values go to Matched column and rest of the values go to NotMatch column

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
;WITH TempTable(A, B) AS(
    SELECT 1, 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1
)
,CTE(Val) AS(
    SELECT A FROM TempTable UNION ALL
    SELECT B FROM TempTable
)
,Match AS(
    SELECT
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Val),
        Val
    FROM CTE c
    GROUP BY Val
    HAVING COUNT(Val) > 1
)
,NotMatch AS(
    SELECT
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Val),
        Val
    FROM CTE c
    GROUP BY Val
    HAVING COUNT(Val) = 1
)
SELECT
    Match   =   m.Val, 
    NotMatch=   n.Val
FROM Match m
FULL JOIN NotMatch n
    ON n.Rn = m.Rn
```

Comment: Thanks! The OP's design is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Try with EXCEPT, MINUS and INTERSECT Statements. 
like this:

```
SELECT A FROM TABLE1 INTERSECT SELECT B FROM TABLE1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    C.A as A 
FROM 
    Table c  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Table d 
    ON 
    c.A=d.B
WHERE
    d.ID IS NULL
```

Please Note that I use `d.ID` as an example because I don't see your schema. An alternate is to explicitly state all `d.columns IS NULL` in `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is kind of - let's call it - interesting. Here is a way to solve it using pivot. Personally I would have chosen a different table structure and another way to select data:

Test data:

```
DECLARE @t table(A TINYINT, B TINYINT)

INSERT @t values
(1,5),(2,1),
(3,2),(4,1)
```

Query:

```
;WITH B AS
(
  ( SELECT A FROM @t
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT B FROM @t)
   UNION ALL
  ( SELECT B FROM @t
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT A FROM @t)
), A AS
(
  SELECT A val
  FROM @t
  INTERSECT
  SELECT B
  FROM @t
), combine as
(
  SELECT val, 'A' col, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) rn FROM A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT A, 'B' col, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) rn
  FROM B
)
SELECT [A], [B]
FROM combine
PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR [col] IN ([A], [B])) AS pvt
```

Result:

```
A    B
1    3
2    4
NULL 5
```